# How to convert String to byte array

Tags: arduino-uno, string, convert

I have the code, it's purpose is to receive the string from a comport like:
`Set@1234567890123456@1234567890123456@1234567890123456@1234567890123456`
and translate it into four byte arrays `byte user1[16], user2[16], pass1[16], pass2[16]`. Here's the code:

```
String inString = ""; // COM port incoming data buffer

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Start");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  // Receive data from com port
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int inChar = Serial.read();


    if (inChar != '\n') {
      inString += (char)inChar;
    } else {
      // New line
      String Action = inString.substring(0, 3);
      if (Action == "Set") {
        SetCard(inString);
      } else if (Action == "Get") {
        Serial.println("1");
      } else {
        Serial.println(Action);
      }
      inString = "";
    }
  }
}

void SetCard(String Data) {
  Serial.println(Data);
  // Data Set@user1@user2@pass1@pass2
  // Set@1234567890123456@1234567890123456@1234567890123456@1234567890123456
  byte user1[16], user2[16], pass1[16], pass2[16];

  String user1str = inString.substring(4, 20);
  String user2str = inString.substring(21, 37);
  String pass1str = inString.substring(38, 54);
  String pass2str = inString.substring(55, 71);

  Serial.println("Strings");
  Serial.println(user1str);
  Serial.println(user2str);
  Serial.println(pass1str);
  Serial.println(pass2str);

  Serial.println("Arrays");
  user1str.getBytes(user1, 16);
  user2str.getBytes(user2, 16);
  pass1str.getBytes(pass1, 16);
  pass2str.getBytes(pass2, 16);


  writeByteArray(user1, 16);
  writeByteArray(user2, 16);
  writeByteArray(pass1, 16);
  writeByteArray(pass2, 16);
}

void writeByteArray(byte array[], int arrlength)
{
  for (int j = 0 ; j < arrlength ; j++) //print the block contents
  {
    Serial.write (array[j]);//Serial.write() transmits the ASCII numbers as human readable characters to serial monitor
  }
  Serial.println("");
}
```

When I run this code and send my string through a com port I expect the output:

```
Start
Set@1234567890123456@1234567890123456@1234567890123456@1234567890123456
Strings
1234567890123456
1234567890123456
1234567890123456
1234567890123456
Arrays
1234567890123456
1234567890123456
1234567890123456
1234567890123456
```

And yet, I receive

```
Start
Set@1234567890123456@1234567890123456@1234567890123456@1234567890123456
Strings
1234567890123456
1234567890123456
1234567890123456
1234567890123456
Arrays
123456789012345
123456789012345
123456789012345
123456789012345
```

Why? And how do I receive desired output?
[getBytes docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringGetBytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why? And how do I receive desired output? getBytes docs

The String member function [getBytes](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.cpp#L547)() will null-terminate the string. You must add space for that.

```
  byte user1[17], user2[17], pass1[17], pass2[17];
  ...
  user1str.getBytes(user1, sizeof(user1));
  ...
  Serial.print((char*) user1);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. So, how can I truncate `user1[17]` array to `user1[16]` after I set it value with getBytes?

Comment: Or do I need to create a buffer array[17] and then write the first 16 elements from there to array[16]?

Comment: Come to think of it I could just   ```for (int j = 0 ; j < sizeof(user1) ; j++) 
  {
    user1[j] = user1str.charAt(j);
  }``` and it would work with 16 elements

Answer (score 1):

Using String.getBytes(buffer, len) to get bytes.

"len" is the length to copy, but usually need to add 1 for the end of string '\0'.

For example:

```
String s = "123";
int count = s.length();  // lenth() is 3
s.getBytes(buffer, count);   // copied "12\0" => HEX(31 32 00)
s.getBytes(buffer, count + 1);   // copied "123\0" => HEX(31 32 33 00)
```

The official document not mentioned those above, and it's not reasonable for the modern function design.

Misunderstanding in that and waste our life so much.

Comment: toCharArray() is documented https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/tochararray

Comment: toCharArray(buffer, len) will still keep the last bye for 0x00 ('\0'). So if want to copy the specific length of the content, len should add 1 for '0'. Also, care the buffer length as the last damn byte.

Comment: that is what is expected for char-array (C string) (but not expected for getBytes)

Comment: If the official document has mentioned the '\0' in details, it's fine for purpose. It's pity for none.

Comment: I am heaving difficulties reading your post and comments. How do you declare `buffer`?